# Laravel 5.4 installation error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am setting up my project using laravel installer command,

```
laravel new blog
```

But it returns the following errors.

```
PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/blog/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/blog/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/blog/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

**My development environment setup:-**

```
Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit
Composer version 1.0.2
Laravel Installer 1.3.3
PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
```

Comment: Try to do `composer self-update` or `composer global dump-autoload`. then look at laravel 5.4 requirements and make sure you have it all :)

Answer (score 0):

Your composer is pretty old.

Try `composer self-update` and make sure your PHP have permission to write file to you current folder

Answer (score 0):

Install these and like the above said, check permissions.
php7.0
libapache2-mod-php7.0
php7.0-cli
php7.0-common
php7.0-mbstring
php7.0-gd
php7.0-intl
php7.0-xml
php7.0-mysql
php7.0-mcrypt
php7.0-zip
php7.0-fpm
php7.0-bz2
php7.0-json
php7.0-tidy
php-redis 
php-memcached

```
sudo apt install -y php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-mbstring php7.0-gd php7.0-intl php7.0-xml php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-zip php7.0-fpm php7.0-bz2 php7.0-json php7.0-tidy php-redis  php-memcached
```